# Angular shared module breaks console.log()

Tags: angular, angular15

I have an Angular app in which my *app-routing.module.ts* uses lazy loading for different modules(pages in my case). Now I have a generic *shared.module.ts* in which I have some common components which I use in all of my lazy loaded modules. However in one particular case I managed to reutilize several components for 2 of my lazy loaded modules, hence I needed another shared module - *other-shared.module.ts*. Everything seemed to work fine, data is loaded, HTML looks fine, directives are working, however console.log() statements do not work any longer, they are simply not displayed in the console anymore. Which is strange because in all of the other places in my app (including components from *shared.module.ts* console.log() works fine). If somebody encountered this how did you manage to solve it? I will provide the chain of modules here for clarity:

***app-routing.module.ts***

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/home/home.module').then(
        (m) => m.HomeModule,
      ),
  },
...
```

***shared.module.ts***

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ToastsContainer,
    LangSwitchComponent,
    ValidationMessagesComponent,
    ConfirmModalComponent,
    ErrorIconComponent,
    ValidationMessagesComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgbTooltipModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    TranslateModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ToastsContainer,
    LangSwitchComponent,
    ValidationMessagesComponent,
    ConfirmModalComponent,
    ErrorIconComponent,
    ValidationMessagesComponent,
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgbTooltipModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    TranslateModule,
  ],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

***other-shared.module.ts***

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Component1,
    Component2,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [SharedModule, DragDropModule],
  exports: [
    SharedModule,
    Component1,
    Component2,
    ...
  ],
})
export class OtherSharedModule {}
```

***some-lazy-loaded-page-module.ts***

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: Page1MainComponent }];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [Page1MainComponent],
  imports: [SharedModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
})
export class LazyLoadedPageModule {}
```

***lazy-loaded-page-where-I-use-my-other-shared-module.ts***

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: MainComponent }];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainComponent,
    SubComponent1,
    SubComponent2,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    OtherSharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
})
export class LazyLoadedPageWithIssueModule {}
```

Initially I had no idea why the console.log was not working, but in the end I managed to pinpoint the issue to modules. At first I moved the components to a single page module and disabled the second page - everything worked. Then I moved the components back to the *other-shared.module.ts* and imported it in pages, but I kept only 1 page and commented the other - and it still worked fine. Then I enabled the second page again. As soon as the app is initialized with both lazy loaded modules containing the *other-shared.module.ts* the console log stops working, which hints to the fact that somehow when the module is used in both pages the console crashes in some way, however again, in all other parts of the app it works, and the most important is the fact that in works in components which are registered under the initial *shared.module.ts*. So I really do not understand why it does not work in that case. In the end I just commented out the *other-shared.module.ts* and moved the components to the generic *shared.module.ts* and console.log() again starting working. I would still like to solve the issue because now I import those components in all of my lazy loaded modules, but I need it only for 2 in terms of optimization.

**EDIT:**
I have a *base.component.ts* which I use for generic functions/services I use trough my app, from which most of my components are extended. I noticed that the components in my *shared.module.ts* do not extend from it, while the ones in *other-shared.module.ts* actually do.

***base.component.ts***

```
export class BaseComponent {
  protected toastService: ToastService;
  protected translateService: TranslateService;
  protected loggerService: LoggerService;
  protected validatorService: ValidatorService;

  constructor() {
    this.toastService = AppInjector.injector.get(ToastService);
    this.translateService = AppInjector.injector.get(TranslateService);
    this.loggerService = AppInjector.injector.get(LoggerService);
    this.validatorService = AppInjector.injector.get(ValidatorService); // Initialize here instead of each component
  }
...
```

The thing here is that I did not what to import the services in each component every single time and call super() with 4 arguments, but rather use *AppInjector* and then I have access to those services in each component right away.

***logger.service.ts***

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoggerService {
  level: LogLevel = LogLevel.Info;
  logWithDate: boolean = true;

  constructor() {
    this.level = environment.logLevel;
  }

  public get debug(): LogFunction {
    if (!this.shouldLog(LogLevel.Debug)) return () => null;
    const now = new Date();
    const time = `[${now.getHours()}:${now.getMinutes()}:${now.getSeconds()}]`;
    const type = `Type: ${LogLevel[LogLevel.Debug]};`;
    const style =
      'color:' +
      LogColor.Default +
      ';font-weight:bold; background-color: ' +
      LogColor.Debug +
      ';';

    return console.log.bind(
      window.console,
      `%c ${time} ${type} Message: %s`,
      style,
    );
  }
...
```

The *logger.service.ts* is a service used to have console.log() with different colors for various log levels for better readability by binding the console.

Comment: Haven't heard of this before, but my first thought is that `console` or `console.log` is being overwritten somehow. In your browser console, I would check what the value of both of those things are.

Comment: @Geo242 Thank you for the tip! The browser did not provide information, however thanks to you I realized it might actually come from the _logger.service.ts_ ts that I am using (edited the post), since the shared components extend from _base.component.ts_ in both pages. Might it be that I have to reject the idea of _AppInjector_ and I will have go trough each single component and init the services there and pass those in  the `super()` call? However does not that still keeps the issue with overriding even if I initialize the _logger.service.ts_ differently?

Comment: If you are using Angular 16+, I recommend using the `inject` function (https://angular.io/api/core/inject) rather than `AppInjector`. Then you can just call it in the base class without passing it into the constructor (`protected toastService = inject(ToastService)`).

Comment: While it did not solve the issue, is is considered a better practice than a manual AppInjector service, hence thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You should not override console.log. Especially not multiple times if debug function is called more than once. Also keep in mind that `console` and `window.console` are the same object.

Instead use the LoggerService for printing the log messages to the console.

For example:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoggerService {
  level: LogLevel = environment.logLevel;
  logWithDate = true;

  public debug(message: string): void {
    if (!this.shouldLog(LogLevel.Debug)) return;

    const now = new Date();
    const time = `[${now.getHours()}:${now.getMinutes()}:${now.getSeconds()}]`;
    const type = `Type: ${LogLevel[LogLevel.Debug]};`;
    const style = `color: ${LogColor.Default}; font-weight: bold; background-color: ${LogColor.Debug};`;

    console.log(`%c ${time} ${type} Message: ${message}`, style);
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help, the error still persists. The console.log.bind() is used so in `dev tools` the log will actually output the real location of the code line, otherwise using it like in this function will always show that the console.log() comes from LoggerService, so something like `logger.service.ts:32`, which does not provide correct info, but thank you for the answer!

Comment: I agree with @SaschaA1982. overriding `console.log` is an anti-pattern. If you need to provide context about where the log message is coming from, it should be in the text of the log. Or create a service that provides you with the message text to log and then just call `console.log` directly. Something like `console.log(LogService.getMessage('Test'))`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however the error still persists even with a full override of the service.